# How to use Application Helpers in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to post a random testimonial on each page of a site.

I started off by using an application helper like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def random_testimonial
    @random_testimonial = Testimonial.find(:first, :offset => rand(Testimonial.count))
  end

end
```

In my view I can reference the method but it's being called on each reference, which makes sense.

I'd like this to be called once on each page view exposing a Testimonial object I can use within the view.

What should I be looking for to do this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

While that works, and I have certainly been known to do this, it violates the MVC separation of concerns. View helpers are not supposed to contain controller/model type logic, which this does.

You might consider refactoring this back into the application controller.  Helpers are supposed to be for view formatting and stuff, more than as a function (which is what I kept wanting to do when I got started.)

If you got back into your Testimonail model, do could do

```
def self.random
  Testimonial.find(:first, :offset => rand(Testimonial.count))
end
```

then in your application controller, you could do:

```
def random_testimonial
  @random_testimonial ||= Testimonial.random
end
```

and call it from a before_filter

This has the advantage of moving the database logic back into the model where it belongs.

Comment: Agreed. Voted up your solution, Scott. Chris, I'd recommend you to select Scott's answer as a correct one. I was too focused on the problem of caching the variable and missed this obvious flaw in the design.

Comment: This is really old I know, but this isn't correct. The View in MVC can QUERY the model, it just can't MANIPULATE it. View Helpers, therefore, can inquire the model state independently of controllers.

Comment: @sunwukung Actually this post is correct. Too often Rails _VIEW_ helpers become a dumping ground for procedural business logic. The point here is SOC. The view should not be instantiating models, nor should it contain model behaviour.

Comment: @azriel - neither of which I'm suggesting. The role of view helpers is formatting, as stated - but the V in MVC is permitted to 'observe' the model, and as such can make queries (not updates) on the model to achieve this. Folks see the C as the fence between the M and the V

Comment: @sunwukung This is not querying the model's state. It is creating a new instance of the model based on some business logic. In fact, in the original code, the view is determining the state of the model.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly, you want a method that returns the same object every time it is referenced in one request/response cycle. If this is true, you can achieve it with a minor change to your helper:

```
 def random_testimonial
    @random_testimonial ||= Testimonial.find(:first, :offset => rand(Testimonial.count))
 end
```

Notice the "||=" part. That's a Ruby idiom which says: assign a value to @random_testimonial, unless it already has a value.

Hope that answers your question.